# Reading infinite stream - tail

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, generator, pipeline

> ## Problem:
>
> Program to read the lines from infinite stream starting from its end of file.

#Solution:

```
import time
def tail(theFile):
    theFile.seek(0,2)   # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
        line = theFile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(10)    # Sleep briefly for 10sec
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fd = open('./file', 'r+')
    for line in tail(fd):
        print(line)
```

---

`readline()` is a non-blocking read, with if check for every line.

**Question:**

It does not make sense for my program running to wait infinitely, after the process writing to file has `close()`

1) What would be the EAFP approach for this code, to avoid `if`?

2) Can generator function return back on `file` close?

Comment: _"What would be the EAFP approach for this code, without if check?"_ - Nothing really. The reason you're using an if statement is not to keep Python from raising an error, but to verify that `line` actually has useful contents to return. Python doesn't care whether or not that is true. It would yield `line` regardless without raising an error.

Comment: @ChristianDean EAFP does not encourage condition check of a name before referring(`yield line`) that name.

Comment: I understand that. But there's nothing to ask forgiveness _for_. Your not doing anything wrong from Python's perspective. Again, **Python does not care if** `line` **is empty or not**. It will execute `yield line` regardless. Using a `try/except` block here is practically useless. Just stick with `if`.

Comment: @ChristianDean  That forgiveness can be to `continue` in the loop. Forgiveness section does not need to raise exception. Shouldn't I write `continue` in `except` block?

Comment: OK. But that still doesn't solve the problem. **There is not exception to ask forgiveness _for_**. No error will be raised in your function because `line` is empty. Thus, it makes no sense to ask for forgiveness.

Comment: @ChristianDean Ok, Yes. There is not exception to ask forgiveness. Got u

Comment: @ChristianDean How to terminate my program, if multiple data is being retrieved from multiple sources? as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/kuNBB92S)

Comment: Sorry @overexchange. I am a busy right now and cannot answer your question. If you have another question though, you should really post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ChristianDean in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895527/reading-infinite-stream-tail/44895660#comment76769078_44895527) answered your first question quite nicely, so I'll answer your second.

I do believe it is possible - you can use `theFile`'s `closed` attribute and raise a `StopIteration` exception if the file was closed. Like this:

```
def tail(theFile):
    theFile.seek(0, 2) 
    while True:
        if theFile.closed:
            raise StopIteration

        line = theFile.readline()
        ...
        yield line
```

Your loop shall cease when the file is closed and the exception is raised.

---

A more succinct method (thanks, Christian Dean) that does not involve an explicit exception is to test the file pointer in the loop header.

```
def tail(theFile):
    theFile.seek(0, 2) 
    while not theFile.closed:
        line = theFile.readline()
        ...
        yield line
```

Comment: Your right, he could implement a generator this way. However, the `StopIteration` is really only superfluous. All he has to do is break from his while loop when the file closes(`while not theFile.closed`), and that's all. Python will handle raising the `StopIteration` for the generator automatically. You don't have to raise `StopIteration` unless your creating a custom generator object.

Comment: @ChristianDean Totally makes sense! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @ChristianDean  `theFile.closed`? Does this work? My program has opened `file` for reading(thru `fd`), How can `theFile.closed` be `True`? This does not work

Comment: @overexchange You are familiar with passing references, yes? `tail` will refer to the same `fd`, so that when you close it outside, the attribute will update.

Comment: So, this `close()` has to be done asynchronously by calling program that passed `fd`

Comment: @overexchange asynchronously or synchronously... doesn't matter... but `tail` will notice the change.

Comment: @overexchange If you liked to see that coldspeed's code does indeed work, I created a little repl.it session [here](https://repl.it/JM21/1). As you may can tell, when we call `fd.close()` inside of the for loop, the generator ends on its next call and stops short before reading all of the data in `file.txt`. This shows that it does respond to `fd` being closed from outside the function. The only thing to note is that I removed `theFile.seek(0, 2)` because that would note produce any visual output, which I thought was important to demonstrate the point.

Comment: @ChristianDean Beauty :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It sure is. _sniff_. It sure is.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. Took long enough! :-) [Now to see what new privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) I have ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148265/discussion-between-christian-dean-and-cs).