# How to read a csv file in tail -f manner using python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read the csv file in a manner similar to `tail -f` i.e. like reading an error log file.

I can perform this operation in a text file with this code:

```
 while 1:
      where = self.file.tell()
      line = self.file.readline()
      if not line:
        print "No line waiting, waiting for one second"
        time.sleep(1)
        self.file.seek(where)
      if (re.search('[a-zA-Z]', line) == False):
        continue
      else:
        response = self.naturalLanguageProcessing(line)
        if(response is not None):
          response["id"] = self.id
          self.id += 1
          response["tweet"] = line
          self.saveResults(response)
        else:
          continue
```

How do I perform the same task for a csv file? I have gone through a link which can give me last 8 rows but that is not what I require. The csv file will be getting updated simultaneously and I need to get the newly appended rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Connecting A File Tailer To A `csv.reader`

In order to plug your code that looks for content newly appended to a file into a `csv.reader`, you need to put it into the form of an iterator.

**I'm not intending to showcase correct code, but specifically to show how to adopt *your existing* code into this form, without making assertions about its correctness.** In particular, the `sleep()` would be better replaced with a mechanism such as inotify to let the operating system assertively inform you when the file has changed; and the `seek()` and `tell()` would be better replaced with storing partial lines in memory rather than backing up and rereading them from the beginning over and over.

```
import csv
import time

class FileTailer(object):
    def __init__(self, file, delay=0.1):
        self.file = file
        self.delay = delay
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            where = self.file.tell()
            line = self.file.readline()
            if line and line.endswith('\n'): # only emit full lines
                yield line
            else:                            # for a partial line, pause and back up
                time.sleep(self.delay)       # ...not actually a recommended approach.
                self.file.seek(where)

csv_reader = csv.reader(FileTailer(open('myfile.csv')))
for row in csv_reader:
    print("Read row: %r" % (row,))
```

If you create an empty `myfile.csv`, start `python csvtailer.py`, and then `echo "first,line" >>myfile.csv` from a different window, you'll see the output of `Read row: ['first', 'line']` immediately appear.

---

#### Finding A Correct File Tailer In Python

For a *correctly-implemented* iterator that waits for new lines to be available, consider referring to one of the existing StackOverflow questions on the topic:

- [How to implement a pythonic equivalent of tail -F?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f)
- [Reading infinite stream - tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895527/reading-infinite-stream-tail)
- [Reading updated files on the fly in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476763/reading-updated-files-on-the-fly-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much!
My issue has been resolved because of your answer and also because of your way of explaining things(concepts).